# Emulating multiple and dynamic inheritance without PHP Traits below 5.4?

Tags: php, traits

Background : in PHP 5.4 there are now traits which allow you to composite classes in a way that you can re-use those 'mixins' anywhere else too. That is being widely used in horizontal programming and comes with important benefits : reducing code bloat.

Question :

1. how to emulate the very same behavior on lower PHP versions by not going over the decorator pattern and static code generators ?

Requirements: the solution should work as you would expect from a language with proper multiple inheritance; also member-variable override in the order you've defined in the list of base-classes.

Solution(s) I have found so far :

1. The only real candidate at hand I've found so far is the 'class-mixer' over [here](https://github.com/wellspringworldwide/PHP-ClassMixer). The problem with this script is that it partly depends on eval which may has some disadvantages. There are also a few other libraries but non of them really turned well, ie : constructor inheritance
2. Not really but acceptable results: Code-Generators as in Doctrine and others.
3. the last solution which came up was to emulate 'multiple inheritance', using the same approaches as in Javascript libraries, ie: implementing the [C3 based algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization).

thanks!

Comment: If there's a common location where something might be called, you could implement a hooks system. Search for "PHP hooks" to see some examples of how to set up a registration/callback system.

Comment: Hi, I thought about this too and tried a few things with our own hook system. The problem with this way was that you end-up with very complicated algorithms to keep control over ownership and priorities. May we didn't try hard enough, but seriously, its pretty hard that way.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine. I guess though if you've something to do with "ownership" then you are doing more than traits offer anyway. If you really can't install 5.4 then I imagine there should be a flexible component out there for this already. Maybe the hooks library from Wordpress (I don't know if it works standalone mind you) or something from Zend or Symfony.